# Auto return won't work

Tags: paypal

I can not get Auto return to work- I have enabled Auto Return and supplied url in both my sandbox account and in the real account.

The IPN is working fine.

Here is example of my request:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?item_name_1=Testing&quantity_1=1&amount_1=719&cmd=_cart&business=test1234@gmail.com&upload=1&rm=1&currency_code=SEK&shopping_url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.public.testing.se%2F&return=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.public.testing.se%2Fcart%2Fok&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.public.testing.se%2Fcart%2Fcancel&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.public.testing.se%2Fcallback%2Fpaypal&custom=23

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to return the data via a GET instead of a POST.  If you are wanting to returnt he data via a GET method, you should use PDT.  There have been issues with returning the data back by a GET and using `rm=1`.  The documentation needs to be updated.  If you want to return the data via a GET method, you need to set up PDT in your account, set the URL, and code your script to do a post back to PayPal using your PDT Token.  PDT also alows you to validate the data so that your URL can not be spoofed.  You can find more on PDT [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/).

If you are wanting the data to be returned to your return URL via a POST rather than a GET, then you need to set `rm=2`.